# How to get the connection state to S3 server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hello I am trying to connect to the S3 server and while I’m trying to get the connection state I can’t find any pre defined api that does that. I’m currently using boto3 with python for this. Anyone with any idea how to constantly get the connectivity state to show if it’s connected or disconnected to the S3? it’s for display.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "state". All requests are REST API calls. Once an API call is finished, there is no on-going connection between the systems.

Think of it like sending an email -- once an email has been sent to a server, there is no 'state' between the sending machine and the email server. They have no need for a 'connection state'.